# SQL Server Computed Column - primary key to alpha characters

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I need to create, and then store in the db table, an alpha representation of a primary key.

I found a wonderful PHP script that does exactly what I want. However, I am not sure of the best way to implement it directly in SQL Server.

I believe that I should be using a persistent Computed Column..? However, I am not sure how to convert the PHP function into one that work in SQL Server. Any assistance/education would be greatly appreciated.

## The PHP code:

```
function alphaID($n)
{
    for ($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1) {
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    }
    return str_pad($r, 6, 'A', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo alphaID(0) . "<br>"; // returns "AAAAAA"
echo alphaID(1) . "<br>"; // returns "AAAAAB"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I am not even going to try to decipher that PHP because I have never written a line of it. Can you explain what that does?

Comment: Why not just store the key? Even if there's a reason the actual key can't be stored why convert that in *SQL*? You can't apply that function to fields in queries if you want to use indexes on them which means all primary, foreign key values will have to be converted *before* they get stored in the database. The key itself will end up being quite a bit bigger than the actual ID too. A single letter can represent only 26 out of the 256 possible values a char can  hold

Comment: @SeanLange

The PHP script will take a number and convert it to a unique alpha-only string.

For example:

"0" returns "AAAAAA"
"1" returns "AAAAAB"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
The alpha-id is required by the client. They need a '6-digit alpha-only' code to represent the primary key.

Comment: How is something like that useful?

Comment: @mvanolden that would still be a bad key. The key should remain a proper key. What you ask should be a computed "display only" field that isn't used in relations.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! @LukStorms was able to provide the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a User Defined Function for this

```
create /*or alter*/ function fnIntToPaddedBase26(@i int) 
returns varchar(7) 
as
begin
  declare @out varchar(7) = '';

  if @i = 0
    set @out = 'A';
  else
    set @i += 1;

  while @i > 0
    select @i -= 1, @out = char(ascii('A') + @i%26) + @out, @i/=26;

  if len(@out)<6
    set @out = right(replicate('A',6)+@out,6);

  return @out;
  end;
GO
```

Then use the UDF

```
select dbo.fnIntToPaddedBase26(167854565) as int2char;
```

returns:

```
NCHENV
```

Comment: You nailed it @LukStorms!   The only edit I made was to change the lowercase 'a' to uppercase. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: a follow up question @LukStorms... How would I use this to create a persistent computed column? Can you please show me what the formula would be?  Something like:    dbo.fnIntToPaddedBase26(uniqueidhere)   ?   Would it be better if I created a trigger instead?

Comment: Not sure if it can be used as a persisted. Because I'm guessing that ms sql would complain that it's not deterministic.  But something like `ALTER TABLE TableName ADD charcol AS dbo.fnIntToPaddedBase26(intcol);` for non-persisted. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql)  And I've changed it back to uppercase 'A'. Because 'AA' & 'AAA' are both 0, I think.  Btw, maybe you could make the UDF deterministic. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651662/). But I never tried that.

Comment: Thanks again @LukStorms!

Comment: @mvanolden You're welcome. Btw, the `varchar(7)` is because above 321272405 you get 7 letters. And weird enough, 321272406 returns 'AAAAAAA'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `convert()`?

```
alter table t as pk_string as (convert(varchar(255), pk_column));
```

This adds a new computed column called `pk_string` which is the string representation of `pk_column`.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt Gordon. However, this solution only converts the number into a string. 

I am looking to have the primary key (number) converted into alpha characters. That is what the PHP script in my original question is doing. 

Some output from the script above:

      0 returns AAAAAB
      1 returns AAAAAB
      167854565 returns "NCHENV"


I need this same output, but in SQL Server code. Also, it must be persistent (a stored value) so that I can search on it.  Thank you again for your attempt.